# Error deploying Ionic app to Android Phone (Ionic 4)

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am running the command `ionic cordova run android` with the usb cable connected as expected. The app builds, and then when it starts to build the apk to deploy on to my phone I'm hit with this error in the terminal.

```
> cordova run android Android Studio project detected ANDROID_HOME=/Users/user/Library/Android/sdk JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_201.jdk/Contents/Home studio Subproject Path: CordovaLib Subproject Path: app publishNonDefault is deprecated and has no effect anymore. All variants are now published. The Task.leftShift(Closure) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use Task.doLast(Action) instead.
        at build_3e7pv4o3p5wholih0470cvjae.run(/Users/user/Documents/BoutiqueSolicitors/BoutiqueSolicitors/platforms/android/app/build.gradle:148) Configuration 'compile' in project ':app' is deprecated. Use 'implementation' instead. :CordovaLib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE :CordovaLib:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE :CordovaLib:compileDebugAidl FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong: null value in entry: incrementalFolder=null

* Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s 1 actionable task: 1 executed /Users/user/Documents/BoutiqueSolicitors/BoutiqueSolicitors/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong: null value in entry: incrementalFolder=null

* Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s [ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

        cordova run android exited with exit code 1.
```

I looked up the error: incrementalFolder=null, and I found that people were saying to fix this error you need to delete .gradle folder inside the root directory of an existing android studio project. I have tried this with no change.

Does anyone know a fix for this? I am clueless, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: run command 'gradlew assembleDebug --debug' from android studio terminal and see if it gives more details on build failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Subproject Path: CordovaLib Subproject Path: app publishNonDefault is deprecated and has no effect anymore. All variants are now published.-----------> No impact.
2. The Task.leftShift(Closure) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use Task.doLast(Action) instead.----------->No impact.
3. at build_3e7pv4o3p5wholih0470cvjae.run (/Users/user/Documents/BoutiqueSolicitors/BoutiqueSolicitors/platforms/android/app/build.gradle:148) Configuration 'compile' in project ':app' is deprecated. Use 'implementation' instead. ---------->Modify dependencies in app/build.gradle to use 'implemntation' instead of 'compile'.
4. :CordovaLib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE :CordovaLib:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE :CordovaLib:compileDebugAidl FAILED.------------>look into your aidl related changes; like definition and location of aidl interface.

run command 'gradlew assembleDebug --debug' from android studio terminal and see if it gives more details on build failure.

[image]

[image]

[image: [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJQRg.png]

Comment: Under dependencies in my build.grade, there is no compile I just have this one line: `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'`

Comment: Running that command in android studio terminal gives me gradlew: command not found error

Comment: Correction - Checked the build.grade of my ionic project instead of in android studio, both my random existing android studio projects build.gradle have "implementation" instead of "compile" already

Comment: shall be able to run this command [gradlew assembleDebug --debug] from android studio terminal.

Comment: bash: gradlew: command not found - and the same effect when I run using sudo prefix

Comment: I am using the correct terminal as illustrated in the image you added to your answer.

Comment: This is the contents of the gradew.bat file you've highlighted in your answer, hope this helps: https://pastebin.com/zngR9cm2

Comment: yes gradlew batch file you shared is correct. Go to folder where gradlew file is present and try to 'Run as administrator'.

Comment: Ran the .sh file instead as I am on Mac, but this solved my issue! Thanks a lot you legend! Marked as correct answer.

Comment: I am glad i could help you.