# Error deploying Ionic app to Android emulator (Ionic 4)

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

im using ionic 4 framework and running the command **ionic cordova run android** using android studio emulator.. then it shows error like this question [Error deploying Ionic app to Android Phone (Ionic 4)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56223386/11410504) .. but still the solution didnt solve my problem..

any help would highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Use the command with --device flag on
**ionic cordova run android --device**

Comment: didnnt works..' native run was not found in your path'